# Prioritizing hook chain?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, keylogger

I'm currently working on a keylogger using the hooks mechanism.
After some research I realised that the hook which I'm adding to the hook chain, is added in the end of it.

So, I've been wondering whether there is a way to place my hook at the beginning of the hook chain, so it'll be used first when hitting the keyboard?

Comment: Clearly that is impossible. You just need to apply the "what if two programs tried this?" test.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is [clearly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#procedures) possible, to set a hook to the front of the hook chain. That's what installing a hook does. It even survives the *"what if two programs did this"* test, with predictable results. What isn't possible (at least not easily) is to make it stay at the front.

Comment: That's precisely what I meant. When two programs attempt to do this, they can't both be first simultaneously. It seems unlikely that the asker really cares whether or not the hook was at one instant in time first.

Comment: Some games monitor their hooks and will reinstall them if they believe the hooks have fallen down the chain order.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Hooks Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#procedures) documentation:

> The [**SetWindowsHookEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) function always **installs a hook procedure at the beginning of a hook chain**. When an event occurs that is monitored by a particular type of hook, the system calls the procedure at the beginning of the hook chain associated with the hook.

Whatever you do, your hook procedure is installed to the front of the hook chain. The same rule applies to every other program that installs a hook, though, so there is no guarantee, that your hook will remain at the beginning of the chain throughout its lifetime.

Comment: This is really odd.
When I created the keyboard hook and I called CallNextHook(), then nothing was called. 
When I created another hook and the called CallNextHook() in the first hook, it called hook #2. So, if the hook was the first one to be called at a keyboard interrupt, it clearly should have called the default system hooks after it, am I wrong?

Comment: What made me thought that the SetWindowHook() places the hook at the end of the hook chain.

Comment: @IdanOfek: What sort of *"default system hooks"* do you have in mind? And how would you determine, whether those are called or not (assuming there were any)?

Comment: Rather than using a keyboard hook at all, look at using [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) instead. The `SetWindowsHookEx()` documentation for keyboard hooks even suggests that: "*In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it should monitor raw input instead.*" Then you don't have to worry about hook order.